# RegEx: Match nth occurrence

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following string:

```
_name=aVlTcWRjVG1YeDhucWdEbVFrN3pSOHZ5QTRjOEJZZmZUZXNIYW1PV2RGOWYrczBhVWRmdVJTMUxYazVBOE8zQ3JNMmNVKzJLM2JJTzFON3FiLzFHUE0xY0pkdz09LS1jbkkwaWoxUUl3YVhMMkhtZHpaOW13PT0"%"3D--57356371d167f"
```

I want to match everything between `=` and the end `"` *(note there are other quotes after this so I can't just select the last `"`)*.

I tried using `_name=(.*?)"` but there are other quotes in the string as well. Is there a way to match the 3rd quote? I tried `_name=(.*?)"{3}` but the `{3}` matches for the quotes back to back, i.e. `"""`

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/uC5eO9/1)

Comment: put `"` inside the parenthesis.

Comment: This still only matches up to the first quote

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b_name=(?:[^"]*"){3}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK0eO2/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b_name`: Match full word `_name`:
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `(?:[^"]*"){3}`: Match 0 or more non-`"` characters followed by a `"`. Repeat this group 3 times.

Comment: This solution even matches **_name=** along with the required match which we don't want! so shouldn't we just add a bracket around like this:  `_name=((?:[^"]*"){3})`  https://regex101.com/r/oK0eO2/374 Please tell me if I got this wrong?

Comment: If you want to capture part after `=` then `_name=((?:[^"]*"){3})` seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

If want to match everything between the first and the third(!) double quote (the third isn't necessarily the last, you told), you can use a pattern like this:

```
$string = '_name=foo"bar"test" more text"';
// This pattern will not include the last " (note the 2, not 3)
$pattern = '/_name=((.*?"){2}.*?)"/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Output:

```
foo"bar"test
```

---

**Original answer:**

I'm not sure if I got you correctly, but it sounds like you want to perform a so called *greedy match*, meaning you want to match the string until the last `"` regardless whether the string contains multiple `"`s.

To perform a greedy match, just drop the `?`, like this:

```
_name=(.*)"
```

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/uC5eO9/2

Comment: This is part of a curl request. There are other quotes after this but I am just looking to match the 3rd quote. Your code will match the _last_ one which is not what I want