# Finding the string or substring within nth occurrence in a line

Tags: regex, string, search, replace, sublimetext3

I would like to find the third occurrence of string inside quotes in order to replace this string or part of this string. This is a typical line I have to deal with:

> "/activities/absenceactivity/lang/#LANG_ID#/prop_dialog.php";"BA2_PD_SCR";"Opis
>   dogodka";"Event description";"DescriÃ§Ã£o do Evento";"ÐÐ¿Ð¸Ñ
>   Ð¿Ð¾Ð´ÑÑ";"";"č®vykio aprašymas";"DescripciÃ³n del evento";"";

I know that "([^"]*)" shows every occurrence of text and quotes but I would like to get just the third one, in this example "Opis dogodka" in order to perform Search & Replace in Sublime Text.

Problem is to find the third occurrence of string within the quotes, replace it entirely or just partially and make sure that the Regex provides also a solution for an empty

> ""

strings.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Match nth occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438693/regex-match-nth-occurence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{}` pattern repetition:

```
/(?:"([^"]*)";){3}/   # first match group will be 'Opis dogodka'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tyA9Hq/1/)

Or, use a global type match and then take the third match. This might require logic such as slicing or looping:

```
/"([^"]*)";/g
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/E8wWkX/2/)

Or, just manually put in the first two patterns to skip:

```
 /^"[^"]*";"[^"]*";("[^"]*";)/
```

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/jHwgl0/1/)

Or combine repetition to skip the first n-1 then capture the nth match:

```
/^(?:"[^"]*";){2}("[^"]*";)/
```

[Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/xOVYYl/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are ways to simplify this further, but if you're ok with brute force:

Sublime command:

```
 Find: "[^"]*";"[^"]*";"([^"]*)".*
 Replace: $1
```

NP++:

```
 Find what: "([^"]*)";"([^"]*)";"([^"]*)".*
 Replace with: $3
```

sed:

```
 sed 's/"\([^"]*\)";"\([^"]*\)";"\([^"]*\)".*/\3/'
```

Comment: Sublime command: "[^"]*";"[^"]*";"([^"]*)".* finds the whole line but I don't know what $1 does. I need to replace particular string within the third quote position and sometimes this is "the whole string within quotes" and in some instances just a substring, for instance just character "s".

Comment: Notice the parenthesis in the search string. `$1`  represents the data in the first set of parentheses from the search string. Check out http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-10

Comment: @andrej It may help it you write out an example of the desired replacement outcome.